# Why download manager requires `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for maxSdkVersion > 18

Tags: android

I'm using `Download manager` to download file and save it to the external storage like this:

```
DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(TextReaderActivity.this, null, "podcasts/" + Integer.toString(article.id) + PODCAST_EXTENSION);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception: need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use DESTINATION_FILE_URI: uid 10052 does not have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
```

I've read that I don't need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for `maxSdkVersion > 18` when writing to external directories, why doesn't it require it here with `DownloadManager`?

UPDATE:

> On Android 4.4 and up, the rules are a bit different: 
>   - To read or write in the directory trees rooted at getExternalFilesDir()
>   and getExternalCacheDir(), you do not need a permission 
>   - To write to anywhere else on external storage, you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   - To read from anywhere else on external storage, you need either
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (if you already have that) or
>   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (if not)

Comment: Where did you read that?(include that source in question)

Comment: Included quote from `CommonsWare` book

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules that you cite regarding `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are for when *your process* writes to external storage, and then only for your `getExternalFilesDir()` and related directories.

In this case, you are not writing to external storage. You are asking `DownloadManager` to write to external storage. `DownloadManager` — or, more accurately, the process that `DownloadManager` talks to — is requiring you to have this permission, and it would appear to do so without regard to API level.

Comment: I see, thanks! You might consider adding this piece to your book since this is where I found the implementation of the `DownloadManager`. As an aside note, you sometimes mentions some web development practices, do you have background in web development too?

Comment: @Maximus: "You might consider adding this piece to your book since this is where I found the implementation of the DownloadManager." -- OK. "do you have background in web development too?" -- some, though that's really off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

The doc for [DownloadManager.Request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri%28android.net.Uri%29) clearly mentions that the destination you set for any of the `setDestination` methods must be on external storage and that your app must have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:

Comment: Thanks, I've udpated my question with relevent quote. So does it mean that `DownloadManager` writes to location other than returned by `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`?

Comment: Yep, yo can set the location by using setDestinationInExternalFilesDir.